# cPanel /Host / Access to phpMyAdmin

Tags: hosting, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I have a host and cPanel access but only one main user and password to cPanel.

I want to give someone access to phpMyAdmin but don't want to give that person my main user and password for cPanel.

Is there anyway to give someone access to phpMyAdmin but not cPanel?

Comment: Can you create mySQL users in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: http://www.webhostinghub.com/support/edu/cpanel/308-how-do-i-install-phpmyadmin-onto-my-account
may help you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The phpMyAdmin which comes with cPanel (in the 3rdparty-directory) is apparently secured with the cpanel-authentication, so the answer is "no".

You could install your own phpMyAdmin (maybe it's even available in the script-center/one-click-installer)  and set it up to directly authenticate on the MySQL-server with your custom MySQL-user or just let your user enter his credentials which you have supplied.

Comment: Great advise bro! I used the 'Softaculous Apps Installer' that came with my cPanel dashboard to install my own 'PHPMyAdmin' that comes with a login form out of the box. I had to create a folder where it was to be installed first though.

Answer (score 3):

As I was looking for an answer to this question, I found the following method that did the job for me:

[How to access phpMyAdmin directly from my domain?](http://kb.siteground.com/how_to_access_phpmyadmin_directly_from_my_domain/)

This worked well for me, although I'm using a **different** hosting provider then Siteground.

Steps I followed:

- Downloaded the **phpmyadmin** installation package. I found the appropriate version, as hosted on my server at [sourceforge.net/projects/phpmyadmin/files/phpMyAdmin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmyadmin/files/phpMyAdmin/)
- Extracted the package.
- Uploaded the files into a suitable folder. I used: public_html/phpmyadmin/
- Now, via the direct URL [http://yourdomain.com/phpmyadmin] I can strictly grant access to a specific database, I have created in cPanel (using the specific user name + password).

Please note this extra security measure:

- For additional security we would also recommend you to [Password Protect the directory](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/pass_protected_directories.htm)  in which the tool is installed.

Answer (score 2):

**You cannot give direct access to your phpMyAdmin without providing direct cPanel access as well.**

This is a security measure from cPanel as phpMyAdmin is known to be one of the most exploited PHP applications of all time. It is only available after you start your session by logging into cPanel.

**A nice work-around this is to do the following:**

Create a MySQL User for the other person. Assign that MySQL User to your Database. Both of those are done through:

**cPanel -> MySQL Databases**

After that you need to allow access for the other person by adding his/hers IP address in your Remote MySQL Connection - this is also a tool in cPanel

After that the other person will be able to connect to your Database without direct access to your cPanel nor phpMyAdmin, it can be done using software like [MySQL WorkBench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Answer (score 0):

cPanel user account has a privileges to control all created databases under cPanel account, And because phpMyAdmin in cPanel is using cPanel authentication you are automatically redirected to the phpMyAdmin control page without asking for login info.

Your target could be done with changing cPanel password without changing mysql user password.

You can do the following steps :

1 - Create MySQL user and add this user to database with full privs.

2 - Create new cPanel account Login through new account Change new cpanel

3 - user password through "Change Password" And un-check Allow MySQL
   password change.

4 - Click phpMyAdmin from the new cpanel account and you
   will be asked for login info

5- Type the login info of the created mysql
   user in step1.

You can now login to the required database without old account cPanel info.

There is another soln is to copy **/usr/local/cpanel/base/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin** to **/usr/local/apache/htdocs** and login through **http://ip/phpMyAdmin**

Don't forget to change the **auth_type** in **/usr/local/apache/htdocs/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php** to http or cookie